How to use same fvm version configuration for the overall project with dependencies?
I am working on a flutter app. In this app I am using fvm as I have to work with older version and it's easy to manage for this project. But there is a problem I am facing in the app. Right I have some dependencies which are on our git account and managed by us. We are adding those like this:
ui_controls:
    git:
      url: "git@github.com:chandra-mbh/ui_controls.git"
      ref: "release/0/9/0.9.85"

Now for this ui_controls I have to manage different fvm as it is different project. I am maintaining same configuration in this ui_controls project too.
I am trying to find a way so I can use same fvm configuration for both of the projects so I don't need to worry about the version mismatch or something else.
